# Django, how to execute function on view? And report when function is done

Tags: django

I added this to change_list.html to add button which hits /updateall :

```
<div class="object-tools">
          {% block object-tools-items %}
            {% if has_add_permission %}
                              <a href="/admin/updateall" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i>&nbsp;
            {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Update ALL{% endblocktrans %}
              </a>            

            {% endif %}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
url(r'^admin/updateall$', myview),
```

Url:

```
from keywords.views import gomoz
url(r'^admin/updateall$', gomoz),
```

views:

```
def gomoz(request):
    scrapeshop()
    # html = "" 
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

This returns nothing(as expected) how to make it return message/notification(like popup) when scrapeshop function is done executing ?

Comment: Please show your views.py.
What is mozapi and are you sure the scrapeshop returns a HttpResponse?

Comment: hi, edited question.

Answer (score 1):

For notifications you should use django messages (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages)

In your case you should add an appropriate message in your gomoz view:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def gomoz(request):
    scrapeshop()
    messages.info(request, 'Your message goes here')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('the-url-of-your-change-list-page')
```

And after you will be redirected to the change list page django admin will display a popup with a message you passed to messages.info method.